# Donde poner el suma=suma+1, (restriccion de while)? c++

Tags: c++, while

Quiero que el código se repita las veces que sea ingresada(en el cin>>cuantos), para eso puse un "suma=suma+1", pero no se donde ponerlo para que se realice, ya que este ciclo se realiza una sola vez, sin importar el numero de veces que ingrese.

```
cout<<"cuantos productos va a consultar?"<<endl;
cin>>cuantos;
do{
    cout<<"ingrese el numero el cual quiere consultar: "<<arreglo[0]<<"="<<"0"<<", "<<arreglo[1]<<"="<<"1"<<", "<<arreglo[2]<<"="<<"2"<<", "<<arreglo[3]<<"="<<"3"<<", "<<arreglo[4]<<"="<<"4"<<", "<<arreglo[5]<<"="<<"5"<<", "<<arreglo[6]<<"="<<"6"<<", "<<arreglo[7]<<"="<<"7"<<", "<<arreglo[8]<<"="<<"8"<<" o "<<arreglo[9]<<"="<<"9"<<endl;
    cin>>numero;
    if(0<=numero<10){
        cout<<"quedan "<<arreglocantidad[numero]<<" de "<<arreglo[numero]<<endl;

     }
    if(numero<0 || numero>=10){
        cout<<"la respuesta ingresada no es valida"<<endl;
    }
    **suma=suma+1;**
}while(cuantos==suma);
```

Comment: Y dónde inicializas suma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo ese bucle **MIENTRAS** *cuantos* sea igual a *suma*, como no es igual en la primera iteracción se sale. La solución sería o bien:

```
while(cuantos > suma);
```

O bien utilizar un while en vez de un do-while:

```
cout<<"cuantos productos va a consultar?"<<endl;
cin>>cuantos;
while(suma < cuantos){
    cout<<"ingrese el numero el cual quiere consultar: "<<arreglo[0]<<"="<<"0"<<", "<<arreglo[1]<<"="<<"1"<<", "<<arreglo[2]<<"="<<"2"<<", "<<arreglo[3]<<"="<<"3"<<", "<<arreglo[4]<<"="<<"4"<<", "<<arreglo[5]<<"="<<"5"<<", "<<arreglo[6]<<"="<<"6"<<", "<<arreglo[7]<<"="<<"7"<<", "<<arreglo[8]<<"="<<"8"<<" o "<<arreglo[9]<<"="<<"9"<<endl;
    cin>>numero;
    if(0<=numero<10){
        cout<<"quedan "<<arreglocantidad[numero]<<" de "<<arreglo[numero]<<endl;

     }
    if(numero<0 || numero>=10){
        cout<<"la respuesta ingresada no es valida"<<endl;
    }
    suma=suma+1;
}
```

A mi personalmente me gusta mas el bucle **while** porque no fuerza una primera iteracción obligatoria. Imaginate que introduces 0 a *cuantos*. El bucle no se debería hacer y con ese do-while se haría la primera iteracción

Comment: muchas gracias, te pasate :).